# Determine if unique number has been seen from a range of numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find the best, quickest and most efficient way to determine if a number has been seen in a range.

**Example:**
Key for record: Raffle Event 1 (database key)

Tickets Available: 1 - 1000000 (the range)

Ticket number 4 was turned in. Has it been turned in already for this event?

Ticket number 865401 was turned in. Has it been turned in already for this event?

I've thought about bit masks, storing data as buckets, etc. But none of these seem to be the answer I am trying to find. Maybe it does not exist.

We have 800,000 events, each event with 1 million tickets. We are currently storing the last number turned in, and anything lower is rejected. We want to have finer granularity, but need efficiency and storing each ticket would be impractical.

Data is stored using SQL

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The best idea I've come up with so far is using a bitmap. Have 10 columns for each event. Each column stores 100,000 bits. This should allow for quick data retrieval, then just check if the bit is on or off. This should be about 1mb of storage per event, or 100k per column read.

I'm still searching for alternative ideas or recommendations.

Comment: So... `if 1 <= number <= 1000000: print("In range")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "has been seen from a range"? Give some examples.

Comment: @Kevin: He said 'has been seen in the range'.

Comment: The choices seem to be 1) query the database, or 2) load all the values from the database into an in-memory data structure of some sort and then  search the data structure. How often do you need to check to see if one of these values exists? And are these values indexed in the database? Could they be indexed? What's the application?

Comment: Just do a query to see whether the ticket number exists. Put an index on the column (or since you don't really need any other data, make it the PK). What does the range have to do with this?

Comment: updated with some basic examples. The application is for a digital raffle. Want to avoid cheating while not storing up to 1000000 million records and scanning them all. The previous solution was to store the last number seen, anything less than that number was considered no good, but this is a flawed implementation

Comment: @Asad - We're dealing with 800,000 events. Each event has 1 million tickets. This is a lot of data if I want to see if the ticket number exists. I am hoping for something more elegant

Comment: Have a table with two columns, event id and ticket number, and put have a composite PK on those. When you want to check if a ticket has been submitted, just look for a record with a particular event id and ticket id.

Comment: Regarding your update to the question, it's unclear why your current strategy would work. If you have a range of ticket numbers from 1-10000, and the very first ticket submitted is 10000, does that mean no other tickets can be submitted?

Comment: @Asad - this would work, yes indeed. But that would be 800 trillion rows, no? In the end, this might be the way we have to go, but I was hoping maybe something could exist that would solve the problem better.

Comment: @bugnuker If every conceivable ticket number for every conceivable event is submitted then yeah, you'd have 800 trillion rows. But this seems unlikely if it is a raffle.

Comment: The true number of rows is simply the number of tickets submitted.

Comment: @Asad - We have tried to give out the tickets in order and it has worked to an extent so far, but it was something that was never really turned on either. It was to prevent people copying tickets and it was not a real problem (digitally) until recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a bitmap. I store 1/0 if the ticket was used or not. I split this bitmap into 16 buckets for storage. This was my magic number as it made just under 8K buckets, the perfect size for SQL paging.

Each bucket is null at first until needed. This saves space. This way each even is taking up zero space. And we only use 8K for each "62500" chunk of tickets. (8K)

It is efficient and does everything I need. I played around with compression to save space, but worst case for me was a few trillion records totaling 100GB if all tickets were accounted for (all buckets for each event). This might sound like a lot of space, but with today's cost its nearly negatable and not worth trying to compress the buckets of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bitmask if you anticipate your range to be moderate. Else you could try using a set structure. These can be implemented using binary search trees.

Comment: I'm researching binary search tree. This could be it. Will report soon. Thanks!